# Setting week start/end dates in spreadsheet using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where I track my expenses. Each month has it's own tab (e.g., Jan, Feb,  Mar...).

Within the month tab, I break the month down into four weeks and track my spending weekly.

I have written a script to create a new month tab, but I'm not sure how to set those weekly date ranges since months have different numbers of days (i.e., 28, 30, 31).

[ranges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LH2No.png)

How would I go about setting the following items regardless of the month:
- first day of first week of month
- last day of first week of month
- first day of second week of month
- last day of second week  of month
- first  day of third week of month
- last day of third week of month
- first day of fourth week of month

Comment: Are you familiar with all of the methods described here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I am not, thanks for sharing. After reading the post you linked, I'm still not clear how I apportion the weeks correctly if the month has 28 days versus 31. Any suggestions?

Comment: `function daysInMonth(m=0) {
  return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),m+1,0).getDate();
}`